# How to let user choose a source directory?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html, node.js

I am trying to figure out how I can allow the user to choose a directory, not just select files. I don't care about the files, just the directory. Is there a way to let the user do this? The only way I have figured out is to return a list of drives that is available on the machine that the application is running on.

This isn't quite what I need, since any networked computers do not show up - only the drives that are actually **mapped**. All I need is to let the user choose a source directory and save that server path (`\\my-server-name\path\to\source`) so that the service I have running will process it at the scheduled time.

I'm not sure if the code I have can be modified to show all network computers or if there is already a way/library to let the user browser directories on the server, but I'm stuck. Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
return (from info in driveInfo
   where info.DriveType == DriveType.Network
   select new Drive
   {
      Name = info.Name, Type = info.DriveType, 
      RootDirectory = info.RootDirectory.Name, IsReady = info.IsReady,
   }).ToList();
```

Any non-c# solutions will work too, as long as it can still be integrated in well. Not sure if `NodeJS` or `Html5` or `Javascript` could do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET application, so I figured that was relevant. No?

Comment: You want an ASP.NET application to browse all the network computers visible to the web server and display that to an end user?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I am trying to do. So far between using what I posted above and what I have [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329642/can-i-speed-up-this-query-to-retrieve-all-computers-on-the-domain), I don't have particularly good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a beautiful solution - and it's very far from quick, but if I'm reading your question correctly, this is along the lines of what you're looking for (done in VB.NET).

```
    Dim fbd1 As New FolderBrowserDialog
    Dim type As Type = FolderBrowserDialog1.GetType
    Dim fieldInfo As Reflection.FieldInfo = type.GetField("rootFolder", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    fieldInfo.SetValue(fbd1, DirectCast(18, Environment.SpecialFolder))
    fbd1.ShowDialog()
```

This will dialog a `FolderBrowserDialog` with "Network" as the root folder. Once you click on Network, it will expand to list all network devices that you may view. On my computer, this was pretty slow.

This is a slightly modified solution from the one I found here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20547/How-to-Browse-Network-Folders-using-Folder-Dialog